create a .exe kivy program with a pyinstaller
I have a .py file called calculatrice.py and another .kv file called calco.kv. I am trying to produce an .exe with pyinstaller. Despite the instructions I followed in the kivy ‘Programming Guide “ Create a package for Windows” documentation, the .exe product does not run because it cannot find the calco.kv file.
calculatrice.py:


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from math import*


Config.set('graphics', 'width', '450')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')
Builder.load_file('calco.kv')

class Calco(BoxLayout):
    """docstring for Calco"""
    def __init__(self, **kwarg):
        super(Calco, self).__init__(**kwarg)
#effectuer des operations mathematiques
    def result(self):
        contain = self.ids.text_id.text #stockage du contenu du textinput
        liste= [] #initialisation de la liste 
        indice = len(contain) #trouver la taille de la chaine de caractere pour les iterations
        a = '' 
        b = ''
        try: #essayer ces instructions
            for i in range (indice):
                liste.append(contain[i]) #remplissage de la liste des caracteres du de la chaine de caractere contain
            for n in range (len(liste)):
                if liste[n]=='²':
                    a= liste[n-1]+'*'+liste[n-1] #operation pour calculer le carré
                    liste[n-1]= str(eval(a)) #remplacement de nombre par son carré
            for i in liste:
                if i=='²':
                    pass
                else:
                    b += i
            self.ids.text_id.text = str(eval(b))
        except :
            self.ids.text_id.text = 'Error'
#calcul du discriminant         
    def discriminant(self, polynome):
        liste = []
        self.a = ''
        self.b = ''
        self.c = ''
        for word in polynome:
            liste.append(word)
        operation = ['-', '+']
        try:
            if liste[0] not in operation:
                for i in range(len(liste)):
                    if liste[i]=='-' or liste[i]=='+':
                        liste_1 = liste[0:i]
                        if '²' in liste_1:
                            liste_1.remove('X')
                            liste_1.remove('²')
                            if liste_1 == []:
                                self.a='1'
                            else:
                                for n in liste_1:
                                    self.a += n
                        else:
                            if 'X' in liste_1:
                                liste_1.remove('X')
                                if liste_1==[]:
                                    self.b='1'
                                else:
                                    for n in liste_1:
                                        self.b += n
                            else:
                                for n in liste_1:
                                    self.c += n 
                        new_liste = liste [i+1:]
                        signe = liste[i]
                        break
                for j in range(len(new_liste)):
                    if new_liste[j]=='-' or new_liste[j]=='+':
                        liste_2 = new_liste[0:j]
                        if signe == '+':
                            pass
                        else:
                            liste_2=[signe]+liste_2
                        if '²' in liste_2:
                            liste_2.remove('X')
                            liste_2.remove('²')
                            if liste_2 == ['-']:
                                self.a='-1'
                            elif liste_2 == []:
                                self.a='1'
                            else:
                                for n in liste_2:
                                    self.a += n
                        else:
                            if 'X' in liste_2:
                                liste_2.remove('X')
                                if liste_2 == ['-']:
                                    self.b='-1'
                                elif liste_2 == []:
                                    self.b='1'
                                else:
                                    for n in liste_2:
                                        self.b += n
                            else:
                                for n in liste_2:
                                    self.c += n 
                        new_liste_2 = new_liste [j+1:]
                        signe = new_liste[j]
                        break
                for j in range(len(new_liste_2)):
                    if signe == '+':
                        pass
                    else:
                        new_liste_2=[signe]+new_liste_2
                    if '²' in new_liste_2:
                        new_liste_2.remove('X')
                        new_liste_2.remove('²')
                        if new_liste_2 == ['-']:
                            self.a='-1'
                        elif new_liste_2 == []:
                            self.a='1'
                        else:
                            for n in new_liste_2:
                                self.a += n
                    else:
                        if 'X' in new_liste_2:
                            new_liste_2.remove('X')
                            if new_liste_2 == ['-']:
                                self.b='-1'
                            elif new_liste_2 == []:
                                self.b='1'
                            else:
                                for n in new_liste_2:
                                    self.b += n
                        else:
                            for n in new_liste_2:
                                self.c += n 
                    break
            #si l'operation commence par le signe -
            else:
                signe = liste[0]
                del liste[0]
                for i in range(len(liste)):
                    if liste[i]=='-' or liste[i]=='+':
                        liste_1 =[signe] + liste[0:i]
                        if '²' in liste_1:
                            liste_1.remove('X')
                            liste_1.remove('²')
                            if liste_1 == []:
                                self.a='1'
                            else:
                                for n in liste_1:
                                    self.a += n
                        else:
                            if 'X' in liste_1:
                                liste_1.remove('X')
                                if liste_1==[]:
                                    self.b='1'
                                else:
                                    for n in liste_1:
                                        self.b += n
                            else:
                                for n in liste_1:
                                    self.c += n 
                        new_liste = liste [i+1:]
                        signe = liste[i]
                        break
                for j in range(len(new_liste)):
                    if new_liste[j]=='-' or new_liste[j]=='+':
                        liste_2 = new_liste[0:j]
                        if signe == '+':
                            pass
                        else:
                            liste_2=[signe]+liste_2
                        if '²' in liste_2:
                            liste_2.remove('X')
                            liste_2.remove('²')
                            if liste_2 == ['-']:
                                self.a='-1'
                            elif liste_2 == []:
                                self.a='1'
                            else:
                                for n in liste_2:
                                    self.a += n
                        else:
                            if 'X' in liste_2:
                                liste_2.remove('X')
                                if liste_2 == ['-']:
                                    self.b='-1'
                                elif liste_2 == []:
                                    self.b='1'
                                else:
                                    for n in liste_2:
                                        self.b += n
                            else:
                                for n in liste_2:
                                    self.c += n 
                        new_liste_2 = new_liste [j+1:]
                        signe = new_liste[j]
                        break
                for j in range(len(new_liste_2)):
                    if signe == '+':
                        pass
                    else:
                        new_liste_2=[signe]+new_liste_2
                    if '²' in new_liste_2:
                        new_liste_2.remove('X')
                        new_liste_2.remove('²')
                        if new_liste_2 == ['-']:
                            self.a='-1'
                        elif new_liste_2 == []:
                            self.a='1'
                        else:
                            for n in new_liste_2:
                                self.a += n
                    else:
                        if 'X' in new_liste_2:
                            new_liste_2.remove('X')
                            if new_liste_2 == ['-']:
                                self.b='-1'
                            elif new_liste_2 == []:
                                self.b='1'
                            else:
                                for n in new_liste_2:
                                    self.b += n
                        else:
                            for n in new_liste_2:
                                self.c += n 
                    break   
            disc = eval(self.b+'*'+self.b+'-'+'4'+'*'+self.a+'*'+self.c)
            return str(disc)
        except:
            return 'Entrer un polynomes à trois monomes de haut dégré 2'
#afficher le discriminant du polynome entré
    def print_disc(self):
        disc = self.discriminant(self.ids.text_id.text)
        self.ids.text_id.text = disc
#factorisation du polinome
    def factorisation(self):
        disc =float(self.discriminant(self.ids.text_id.text))
        racine_disc = str(sqrt(disc))
        x0 = eval('('+'-1'+'*'+self.b+')'+'/'+'('+'2'+'*'+self.a+')')
        x1 = eval('('+'-1'+'*'+self.b+'-1'+'*'+racine_disc+')'+'/'+'('+'2'+'*'+self.a+')')
        x2 = eval('('+'-1'+'*'+self.b+racine_disc+')'+'/'+'('+'2'+'*'+self.a+')')
        if float(disc)==0:
            x0 = eval('('+'-1'+self.b+')'+'/'+'2'+'*'+self.a)
            #self.ids.text_id.text = self.a+'('+'X'+str(-*x0)+')'
        print (round(x0, 2), round(x1, 2), round(x2, 2))
        
        
        

class CalcApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calco()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CalcApp().run()
        



calco.kv:


<Calco>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (249, 247, 247)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size     
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 5
    spacing: 5
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 
        size_hint_y: .1 
        TextInput:
            id: text_id
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 5
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 5
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: .2
                padding_top: 5
                padding_bottom: 5
                padding_right: 5
                spacing: 5
                Button: 
                    text: 'X'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button: 
                    text: 'Y'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button: 
                    text: '²'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: 'Δ'
                    on_press: root.print_disc()

                Button:
                    text: 'Fac'
                    on_press: root.factorisation()
            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                padding_right: 5
                spacing: 5
                Button:
                    text: '9'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '8'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '7'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '6'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '5'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '4'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '3'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '2'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '1'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '.'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '0'
                    on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
                Button:
                    text: '='
                    on_press: root.result()
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_x: .25
            spacing: 5
            Button: 
                text: 'Clear'   
                on_press: text_id.text = ''     
            Button: 
                text: '+'
                on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
            Button: 
                text: '-'
                on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
            Button: 
                text: 'x'
                on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text
            Button:
                text: '/'
                on_press: text_id.text = text_id.text + self.text



I've modified the .spec file to take the .kv file into account, but I still get the same error
calculatrice.spec


from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['calculatrice.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

a.datas += [('calco.kv', 'D:\\MON PROJET\\my test kivy\\calco\calco.kv', 'DATA')]

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='calculatrice',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe, Tree('D:\\MON PROJET\\my test kivy\\calco'),
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='calculatrice',
)



This is the error message:


[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\hp\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-07-24_4.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "D:\MON PROJET\my test kivy\calco\dist\calculatrice\_internal\kivy\__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\MON PROJET\my test kivy\calco\dist\calculatrice\calculatrice.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "calculatrice.py", line 10, in <module>
     Builder.load_file('calco.kv')
   File "kivy\lang\builder.py", line 303, in load_file
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'calco.kv'
[16728] Failed to execute script 'calculatrice' due to unhandled exception!



Please help me to solve the problem

In my experience, I have always set the pathex in the spec file as the path to the the folder containing the top level python file. Then, add the kv file to the datas list as ('calco.kv', '.').
Here is a spec file that worked for me with your code:
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['calculatrice.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('calco.kv', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts, 
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='calculatrice',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='calculatrice')

Naming this calculatrice.spec in the same folder as the python code, and running pyinstaller caclulatrice.spec, produced a one-folder bundle containing an executable that worked. Note that I am using Pyinstaller 4.10. Also, be aware that if you produce a one-folder bundle, you must distribute that entire folder and run calculatrice.exe inside that folder.

Can you make changes to my .spec file?
